# Play .ogg file with SDL_mixer in Edge and Safari (emscripten)

Tags: javascript, c++, sdl-2, ogg, emscripten

I've created a program, which uses (SDL2) `SDL_mixer` to play `.ogg` sound files.

It works in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. But it is not working in MS Edge, and Safari, because the lack of ogg sound support.

I've added this command to the `emcc`, which should fix this issue:

```
-s USE_OGG=1
```

But it is still not working.

How is it possible to make `.ogg` sound files work in Edge (and Safari)?

Comment: It seems like work in progress. https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/3985

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

At the moment of this writing, [both Safari and MS Edge won't support .ogg](http://caniuse.com/#search=ogg), as you mentioned.

Since Emscripten compiles to JavaScript, you'd better find a way to make you code accept another audio extension (fallback) supported by Safari and MS Edge, such as .mp3 or .m4a AAC (which is an audio component of mp4).

Comment: I'm not an specialist in Emscripten but if its code compiles to web technologies, at this moment it is impossible to make .ogg extension work on Safari and Edge, they simply doesn't support it. Maybe the code you exposed allows you to enable .ogg where its supported, but it can't force browsers to recognize it. You'd better then look for a fallback.

Comment: If `.ogg` is available in the browser, then it is working without the `-s USE_OGG=1`